# How can we use SQL LIKE operator in a .bat script

Tags: sql, batch-file, sql-server-2012

I'm trying to set up a batch script that basically runs a SQL statement against a database, and if the script returns results it will follow some logic.

Is there a way to use a LIKE operator with % in SQLCMD Just like below. Since .bat files are treating % as a command, currently I am not getting any rows against the query.

```
sqlcmd -S servername -d dbname -E -Q "SELECT * from sometable WITH (NOLOCK) where col_1 like '%SE%'"
```

Answer (score 0):

**In a Batch File you can escape as:**

`&` will be written as `^&`

`%` will be written as `%%`

Two `%%` equals to `%`

**In Direct CMD**

`&` will be written as `^&`

`%` does not need to be escaped